# List, naming alias of pointers and semantics in C

Tags: c, semantics

I've been working on list as part of my project in C programming language. FYI, structures of entry and list are very basic data structure and defined as such

```
typedef struct entry entry_t;
typedef struct list list_t;

struct entry
{
    void * data;
    entry_t * next;
};

struct list
{
    size_t size;
    entry_t * head;
    entry_t * tail;
};
```

`head` and `tail` point to the first and last entries respectively. There is just no such overhead entry as header but all data entries in list, so if there is only one entry in list, `head` and `tail` should point to the same it. Besides, there is such a snippet to delete all entries in list

```
list_t list;
entry_t * current, * next;
for(
    current=list->head,
    next=current->next,
    free(current);
    current!=list->tail;
    current=next,
    next=current->next,
    free(current)
);
```

The issue is that the comparison between values of memory address `current` and `list->tail` point to is evaluated after `current` pointer is freed. Supposing `current` and `list->tail` are now pointing to the same block of memory and then `current` is freed, what is the result of the evaluation and more importantly, is the result (whatever it is) deterministic in all different compilers in your experience? In my case, the program is compiled in MSVC and runs correctly, which says values of memory address `current` and `list->tail` point to are equal after `current` is freed.

Comment: After `free(current)` using `current !=list->tail` is undefined behaviour

Comment: so it's compiler dependent isn't it?

Comment: @hmjd : Using pointer here not the members of struct so , You are saying it's fine.

Comment: @hmjd : Yeah got it, but OP had formulated the questions in way that I got confused.. see the last line of his question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, you are breaking the rules. By 6.2.4 (2)

> The lifetime of an object is the portion of program execution during which storage is guaranteed to be reserved for it. An object exists, has a constant address, and retains its last-stored value throughout its lifetime. If an object is referred to outside of its lifetime, the behavior is undefined. The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when the object it points to (or just past) reaches the end of its lifetime.

of the n1570 draft of the C2011 standard (almost identical in the same place in the C99 standard), after `free`ing `current` its value becomes indeterminate (and if `current` happened to point at the same object as `list->tail` before `free`ing it, the value of `list->tail` becomes indeterminate too). And thus using it in a comparison invokes undefined behaviour.

In a hypothetical implementation that tracks the validity of pointers and checks it for each comparison etc., it could crash or do other funny things.

<del>However, in practice, I don't expect any implementation to do that, so it will almost certainly yield the expected result.</del>

As [WhozCraig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1322972/whozcraig) [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13473278/list-naming-alias-of-pointers-and-semantics-in-c/13473776#comment18432674_13473776), there actually is a platform doing that tracking. However, that treats all invalid pointers as `NULL`, so even there the code in question would produce the expected result, if I understood correctly.

Comment: @Deniel: that's why it's best practice to make pointer NULL after freeing it , right ?

Comment: Best practice is to have it (and all other pointers to the same object) go out of scope immediately after `free`. Setting it to `NULL` is second best.

Comment: There *is* a platform that does enforce this, btw, Daniel. AS/400. All pointers are 128bit linear addresses, and there exists in a master address page a computational bit-set, where each bit represents a 16-byte offset of the process address space. Only when a pointer (which must be 16-byte aligned) holds a *valid* (meaning dereference'able) address is that bit lit. Any pointer value without its bit lit is treated as NULL. Amazingly, this means `int *p = (int *)1; if (p) printf("foo");` prints nothing. Same setup, it means `if (p == NULL)` evals to true. It is an *amazing* system.

Comment: Oh, that's evil, @WhozCraig. Positively evil. Amazing.

Comment: @WhozCraig But, valid `char*` need not be 16-byte aligned, how are those treated?

Comment: The *pointer variable* is 16-byte aligned in memory, what it *points to* is not necessarily. does that make sense ? I.e. the memory address of the pointer is what is tracked in the bit map.

Comment: Ah, sort of makes sense. I wonder how they efficiently deal with multiple pointers to the same object when that reaches the end of its lifetime.

Comment: That is a great question. I never studied it beyond the omfg-they-really-do-that??-stage. A separate heap map that back-tracks their related pointer bit-offsets would be my guess. hard saying.

Comment: +1 It appears I was incorrect. Just to be sure I have understood. Is this is basically stating that after the call to `free()` (end of pointed to object's lifetime) the address that pointer is holding may not be the same as that passed into `free()`. Pass by value ...?

Comment: @hmjd I think you were absolutely right about the validity based on dereferencing (provided head is not null going in). Your argument there is solid. The validity of the *values* as determinate is the part of the standard Dan brought. Whole different (yet strangely related) issue.

Comment: I wanted to reiterate the comment I made that Dan linked in this answer. After reading it I can see why his brow may have risen. It is the *address* of the OS/400 pointer *variable* that is bit-mapped to the validity-check page for validation. The *value* held *in* the pointer variable must have been obtained by valid system call or machine instruction that assign/create dereference'able valid memory locations. If the *value* held in the pointer is not so-blessed, the bit mapped to the memory location where the *pointer* resides is not flagged and the pointer is thus synonymous to NULL. Whew.

Answer (score 2):

Not that it matters at this point, but if you're clearing the list, then pardon the obvious, but who cares what tail (or size) are. They're about to be invalid anyway. Why not simply:

```
// assuming list is a valid
list_t* list;

while (list->head)
{
    entry_t *tmp = list->head;
    list->head = list->head->next;
    free(tmp);
}
list->head = list->tail = NULL;
list->size = 0;
```

Comment: great... I was thinking of doing the same .+1

Answer (score 0):

> what is the result of the evaluation

The C-standard says the result is undefined.

> and more importantly, is the result (whatever it is) deterministic 
>   in all different compilers in your experience

Memory, once allocated by the process, is usually not returned to the OS until the process terminates.
All compilers that I know of will evaluate `current!=list->tail` as false without throwing an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the `for loop` implementation

```
entry_t *current,*prev,*next;  

  for(
        current = list->head;

        current != NULL;

        prev=current,
        current = current->next,
        free(prev),
        prev=NULL
    );
```